# How to get value of SIP header in Freeswitch?

Tags: sip, freeswitch, dialplan

I need to get value of `CALLED_DID` header and do some actions in dialplan, but i don't know how.

I've tried to use ${sip_h_CALLED_DID} but it's empty, because have no `X-` prefix before header name.

Is there any other method to extract value from SIP header?

Please help me, i've read allover the internet but can't find answer.

```
INVITE sip:gw+zadarma-rbcrm@185.70.135.33:65000;transport=udp;gw=zadarma-rbcrm SIP/2.0
Record-Route: <sip:185.45.152.161;lr=on;ftag=as6a38207b>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 185.45.152.161;branch=z9hG4bK26d.6cf33cf5d2cdd6683e8de9503870f397.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 185.45.152.148:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK74d97ef6
Max-Forwards: 69
From: "+79630495339" <sip:+79630495339@sip.zadarma.com>;tag=as6a38207b
To: <sip:346127@185.45.152.161>
Contact: <sip:+79630495339@185.45.152.148:5060>
Call-ID: 401671d34e8247a9694c3da87c97fbbb@185.45.152.148:5060
CSeq: 102 INVITE
User-Agent: Zadarma Voip
Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2019 07:38:22 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces
CALLED_DID: 73433023519
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 415
hostname: sipbalancer-1
cc_num: 346127
cc_counter: 1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading a ton of material, I came to the conclusion:

**Reading of custom header without `X-` prefix is not possible without modifying of source code.**

But this is not acceptable way in my case.

Comment: Please note that this is incorrect. See Marcel Haldemann's answer of adding 'parse-all-header-invites' to the Sofia Profile

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by setting
`<param name="parse-all-invite-headers" value="true"/>` in the **Sofia SIP Profile**. Then all headers from the Invite are set as **sip_i**_Header-Name channel variables.

**Reacting to specific Headears in any other SIP-Messages:**

If you want to react to specific headers on other messages, you can do this via setting the variable **sip_watch_headers** (needs to be exported and prefixed with *nolocal* if you want it for B-leg only)

If the header is detected, you will get a CUSTOM event of the Subclass "sofia::notify_watched_header".

example to detect **Reason** header on B-Leg:

`<action application="export" data="_nolocal_sip_watch_headers=Reason"/>`

Here is an example of the Event looking for a Reason header on the B-Leg, watching the Header "Reason":

```
  "Event-Name": "CUSTOM",
...
  "Event-Calling-File": "sofia.c",
  "Event-Calling-Function": "notify_watched_header",
  "Event-Calling-Line-Number": "1443",
  "Event-Sequence": "98672",
  "Event-Subclass": "sofia::notify_watched_header",
  "SIP-Message": "SIP/2.0 183 Session Progress",
  "Header-Name": "Reason",
  "Header-Value": "Q.850;cause=16",
  "Channel-State": "CS_CONSUME_MEDIA",
  "Channel-Call-State": "DOWN",
  "Channel-State-Number": "7",
...
"Call-Direction": "outbound",
```

This event can be reacted either with Lua by setting a hook script in the Lua configuration or via AMQP / EventSocket.

**How to do react to these events with Lua**

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_lua#Event_Hooks

Example: autload_configs/lua.conf.xml:

```
<configuration name="lua.conf" description="LUA Configuration">
  <settings>
    <param name="module-directory" value="/etc/freeswitch/scripts/?.so"/>
    <param name="script-directory" value="/etc/freeswitch/scripts/?.lua"/>
    <!--<param name="startup-script" value="startup_script_1.lua"/>--> <!-- started at fs startup and maybe lives forever -->
    <hook event="CHANNEL_DESTROY" script="/etc/freeswitch/scripts/on_channel_destroy.lua"/>
    <hook event="CUSTOM" subclass="sofia::notify_watched_header" script="/etc/freeswitch/scripts/on_reason_header.lua"/>
    
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

**Example Lua script**

```
local uuid = event:getHeader("Unique-ID")
local shallHangup = event:getHeader("variable_HangupOnReasonInEarly")
local answerState = event:getHeader("Answer-State")

if (shallHangup ~= nil and shallHangup == "true" and answerState == "ringing") then
    local value = event:getHeader("Header-Value")
    local code = value:match(";cause=(%d*)")
    --local data = event:serialize("json")
    freeswitch.consoleLog("INFO","REASON DETECTED: for: " .. uuid .. "\n")
    api = freeswitch.API()
    api:executeString("uuid_kill " .. uuid .. " " .. code)
end
```

To enable it in dialplan:

```
<action application="export" data="_nolocal_sip_watch_headers=Reason"/>
<action application="export" data="_nolocal_HangupOnReasonInEarly=true"/>
<action application="bridge" data="..."/>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - I'm not sure why the other one is marked as the correct answer! I came here after a random google to find the param name!

It's been there since 2014, so I'm not sure why these answers from 5+ years later have it so wrong.

https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/commit/19dbd07ff8feb21c8ea9ea0b760e4f6ad8e13b0e

Comment: Where did you get the information (settings) to answer this question?  They don't seem to be published anywhere

Comment: @TSG when viewing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Sip values can not be easily extracted.
Prefix the header with X-. Anything else is invalid.

You can recompile mod_sofia - add an extra header reader:

`https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/src/mod/endpoints/mod_sofia/sofia.c`
Example line 11297.

Add this:

```
} else if (!strcasecmp(un->un_name, "CALLED_DID")) {
    switch_channel_set_variable(channel, "called_did", un->un_value);
```

Between:

```
} else if (!strcasecmp(un->un_name, "Geolocation")) {
    switch_channel_set_variable(channel, "sip_geolocation", un->un_value);
```

And:

```
} else if (!strcasecmp(un->un_name, "Geolocation-Error")) {`
    switch_channel_set_variable(channel, "sip_user_location", un->un_value);
```

And retrieve this header in dialplan like this:

```
<action application="log" data="DEBUG Called Did -> ${called_did}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for participating. This is a possible, but not desirable solution.
Because it needs to be done with every new release of FreeSwitch.