# Freeswitch Event Socket Library - is there abstraction like Session as for internal scripting languages like mod_lua?

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to work with FreeSwitch using Event Socket library, and a bit surprised it has no abstraction like Session in internal scripting languages (which can be established, bridged etc using simple API). Is this the case and I have correct understanding?

If I understand well ESL allows to send API commands like `originate` and receive events and it's up to application to understand the state by processing events, so there are no helpers for this, correct?

So even if

> Scripts using the Event Socket Library (ESL) can be run from anywhere
> achieving the same results as built-in languages

it's up to application developer to implement Session abstraction on his side when using ESL, so ESL is low level interface and much more efforts are necessary to, i.g. establish call with `originate`, get it's state (by processing events) and then bridge it i.g. with `uuid_transfer`?

Answer (score 1):

We are using value from "Unique-ID" header field.
The implementation is using the following library with custom addons - https://github.com/esl-client/esl-client.

PS. for LUA: [How to get value of SIP header in Freeswitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038967/how-to-get-value-of-sip-header-in-freeswitch)